# Shift Register Not Working

Tags: shift-register

I am trying to learn how to use a shift register to control 8 LEDs but for some reason my shift register is misbehaving and none of the LEDs are lighting up. I imagine that it's a problem with my wiring? I have replicated the circuit on 123D Circuits.

[image: circuit diagram]

```
//Pin connected to ST_CP of 74HC595
int latchPin = 8;
//Pin connected to SH_CP of 74HC595
int clockPin = 12;
////Pin connected to DS of 74HC595
int dataPin = 11;

void setup() {
  //set pins to output so you can control the shift register
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // count from 0 to 255 and display the number 
  // on the LEDs
  for (int numberToDisplay = 0; numberToDisplay < 256; numberToDisplay++) {
    // take the latchPin low so 
    // the LEDs don't change while you're sending in bits:
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    // shift out the bits:
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, numberToDisplay);  

    //take the latch pin high so the LEDs will light up:
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    // pause before next value:
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the image or the code. Try jiggeling all the connections. I've sometimes had wires not connecting properly in a breadboard.

Comment: Rejiggling the pins seemed to do it,

Comment: It's always the stupidest thing that takes the most time to debug (-:  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

From the Arduino website:

> ### shiftOut()
>
> Description
>
> Shifts out a byte of data one bit at a time. [...]
>
> Note: if you're interfacing with a device that's clocked by rising
>   edges, you'll need to make sure that the clock pin is low before the
>   call to shiftOut(), e.g. with a call to digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW).

You need to pull `clockPin` low before each `shiftOut()` call, as the documentation says.

Also, you have misunderstood the behaviour of the `latchPin`. This can be high or low at any time; it's the *change from low to high* that latches the data into the output cells.

Comment: `digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW); shiftOut(...); digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);`. Isn't he doing that already?

Comment: No, `clockPin` should be low, according to the blurb.

Comment: Aha, clockPin; not latchPin. Missed that after you edited your answer.